# Source of Heinlein quote, “I don’t see how an article of clothing can be indecent. A person, yes.”

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, quotes

I came across this quote

> I don’t see how an article of clothing can be indecent. A person, yes.

In the context I saw it used, it was clearly a quotation of someone else, but unattributed. I searched for it to find the source, and while any number of pages will tell me it’s from Heinlein, absolutely none of them that I can find will tell me the context of the quote—is it from one of his novels? Something he said in an interview? Something else?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a slight variation on a line from [*Job: A Comedy of Justice*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1684) (Chapter 16):

> "What?  Because those shorts, worn alone, are indecent!"
>
> "**I don't see how an article of clothing can be indecent, Alec.  A person, yes.**  Are you saying that *I* am indecent?"

Comment: A *mis*quote, to be precise

Comment: @Valorum Fair.  You win "The Best Kind of Correct" prize for today. ;)

Comment: No doubt the misquote is why it was so hard to find the original context. Thanks!

Comment: The discussion of being "indecent" (although not this particularly interpretation of what that means) is an allusion to *Jurgen, A Comedy of Justice*, to which the title of Heinlein's novel also alludes.

Comment: @Valorum the misquote is from the missing "Alec"?

Comment: @justhalf yes, that is why he wrote ***mis*quote**, because there is something *mis*sing in that quote

Comment: It's also not proper to [attribute quotes from fictional characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/attributing-quotes-to-fictional-characters) in novels directly to the author of the book, unless enough context is kept.

Comment: @jpa  Did you mean to post this comment on the question?  This quote from the book is quite clearly that, and the specific words in question are not attributed to RAH.

Comment: @DavidW Sorry, I meant it as another reason for "misquote" as discussed above. No issue with your answer, it is perfect :)

Comment: @jpa: I've found with that they get upset either way. When quoting from a certain set of detective stories, somebody will complain no matter which way you do it.

Comment: re: quotes from a character vs. author [Are quotes from a character technically quotes from the author?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2409/56) - general conesus: none.... when in doubt attribute _everyone_!

Comment: @Skooba Some of those suggestions are a bit much.  ("And the assistant to the 2nd assistant director's charcuterie plater was...")  My template is "{character} - {work} [{disambiguation as necessary}]," so for example "Roy Batty - *Bladerunner*" or "Johnny Rico - *Starship Troopers* (Heinlein)."